# How to clear ListBox? (ZK)

Tags: java, zk

I have very simple question. I amazed, that couldn't find answer.
How can I make total clearing of ListBox (org.zkoss.zul.ListBox) in ZK Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below clears the Listbox, but maybe causes problems, if a model is used :

```
lb.getItems().clear();
```

Code below  clears the selection :

```
lb.clearSelection();
```

Code below sets a new model, deletes the old one and all items. The Listbox will be empty if the model is empty

```
lb.setModel(model);
```

If you like to get a new set of Items, the last one should be the best.
If you have a List of them use :

```
lb.setModel(new ListModelList<>(myList));
```

Comment: lb.getItems().clear(); don't give necessary result, if I invoke it just before new data filling. But I notice, that data that I cleared by lb.getItems().clear() will appear again, when fill new data in this ListBox. OMG, too many problem...((

Comment: Use setModel(). It is for sure the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [API](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Listbox.html)

```
public java.util.List<Listitem> getItems()
```

> Returns a live list of all Listitem. By live we mean you can add or remove them directly with the List interface. In other words, you could add or remove an item by manipulating the returned list directly.

So removing from this list removes from ListBox.

So ultimately your line would be `listbox.getItems().clear();`

Comment: As Nibil said ,You need to call explicitly setModel() after you call the remove. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are clearing a selected index, use : [clearSelection()](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Listbox.html#clearSelection%28%29);

Answer (score 0):

- even with using `setModel`, the page numbers in the `Listbox` still show the previous contents page no.s
- `getItems.clear()` also does not clear the page numbers in the `Listbox`

edit:

i did find a round about solution for this:
to ensure that even the page numbers are removed along with the list items, one way to do this is:

```
// removes the data items by setting an empty model
// this has to be done before resetting the mold
myListbox.setModel(new ListModelList<String>());

// removes the page numbers by resetting the mold
myListbox.setMold("<b>default</b>");
```

and then when you need to fill data, you have to set the mold to paging and the model with your list of data:

```
List<String> res= myListData(); //the data to be filled in the listbox
myListbox.setMold("<b>paging</b>");
myListbox.setPageSize(15);
myListbox.setActivePage(0);
myListbox.setModel(new ListModelList<String>(res));
```

another way, is to control the visibility of the paging controller:

```
eventListbox.getPagingChild().setVisible(false);
```

Comment: no, it is an observation/comment, i haven't yet found a solution for clearing the zk listbox ALONG with the previous page numbers